# TFX docker image is heavy

Tags: docker, dockerhub, tfx

I was just wondering why [tensorflow/tfx](https://hub.docker.com/layers/tensorflow/tfx/latest/images/sha256-57eb7723408a82d90727b7eb37935e1f9a22706470abd234d8428bda42492c51?context=explore) image is 8Gb while gpu [tensorflow/tensorflow](https://hub.docker.com/layers/tensorflow/tensorflow/2.11.0-gpu/images/sha256-67f1a7b35fd52bdda071c0cd311655be7477f2bc1b6f27e014b9a57231bd55b3?context=explore) image is less than 3gB?
At runtime, I expect tfx container to just load input artifacts, run some tensorflow code and then save output artifacts. So i can't figure out the weight delta.

Thanks and Regards

Youcef

Comment: I guess you can build the image on top of a base Python image, or remove some unwanted folders to get a lighter version.

Answer (score 0):

Here is [some explanation](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfx/issues/3761#issuecomment-843561938) on why it's been so heavy:

> The increase actually happened since 0.28, because we are now basing off a verified build which is compatible with GPU out of box.

You can also build the image yourself on top of a base python image.